Why can DbContext be resolved from the root scope, when the environment is "local", but not "development"?
Why do I need to create a scope for resolving DbContext, only if the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT is "development"?
When the environment is set to "development", I need to resolve the DbContext using a scope: using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope(), as I get the following error without:

Cannot resolve scoped service 'foo.bar.baz.AssetGovernanceContext'
from root provider.

But when the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT is set to "local", I can resolve the DbContext from the root provider (i.e. no scope needed).
Is there root provider the provider normally used to resolve singletons?
# Add DbContext to service collection
services.AddDbContext<AssetGovernanceContext>(options =>
{
    var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer") ?? throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Connection string not found: SqlServer");
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});


# Resolve the DbContext after calling IHost.Build()
public static class HostExtensions
{
    public static IHost EnsureDatabaseCreated(this IHost host)
    {
        var createDatabase = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>().GetValue<bool>("Database:EnsureCreated");
        if (createDatabase)
        {
            using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope(); # only needed if DOTNET_ENIRONMENT isn't "local"
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AssetGovernanceContext>();
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        return host;
    }
}


@Silvermind by default scope validation is enabled only for dev environments for perfromance reasons, please check out my answer for a bit more details.

Without seeing the full setup it is a bit of a guess, but in general (and based on the provided code it seems highly likely) this happens because for development environment ServiceProviderOptions.ValidateScopes is enabled (for perfromance reasons disabled by default for other environments):

true if validation is performed to ensure that scoped services aren't resolved from the root provider; otherwise, false. The default is the value of IsDevelopment(IHostingEnvironment).

Which is the behavior inherited by standard .NET hosting abstractions (there are ways to manipulate it depending on concrete setup but I would recommend against disabling it completely on all environments, arguably you should enable it for your local one).
Since by default AddDbContext/AddDbContextFactory registers context as scoped then the validation will fail (see captive dependency section of the docs), correct approach is to create a scope and dispose it after usage or use factory and dispose context after using it.
See also:

Implicitly sharing DbContext instances via dependency injection:

The AddDbContext extension method registers DbContext types with a scoped lifetime by default.


Use a DbContext factory
What's the difference between AddScoped and AddSingleton in .NET Core Console Application?


Thank you @GuruStron! Why does the root provider hold scoped services in the first place? IsDevelopment(...) evaluate to true when the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT is set to "development", right (not case sensitive)?

Do you know the reason a longer-lived service, e.g. singleton, may not depend on a shorter-lived service, e.g. transient? In the case of transient services, it will be created when the singleton is created, and assuming that nothing will dispose it, it will continue to serve the singleton for the entirety of the application's lifetime?

@Shuzheng "Why does the root provider hold scoped services in the first place" - TBH not sure, highly likely it is the way it is implemented internaly - i.e. there is a single collection of set up services.  "may not depend on a shorter-lived service, e.g. transient" - AFAIK this is not true, singleton services can depend on transient ones, it's only scoped which are "off limits".

@Shuzheng "In the case of transient services, it will be created when the singleton is created, and assuming that nothing will dispose it, it will continue to serve the singleton for the entirety of the application's lifetime" - yes, the transient service will be created with the root scope as the singleton one itself.

So, it's OK to use transient services with singletons? It's just not possible to use scoped services with singletons? In the case of scoped services, they will be created by the .NET framework in a scoped context (using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope(); ) and they will all be disposed (deleted), when the scope is exited (return response), so the singleton would stop working. Is that understood correctly?

"it's OK to use transient services with singletons" - yes, but there are caveats (the resolved transient service instance will live as long as the singleton one i.e. for the whole app lifetime). "so the singleton would stop working" - no it will not, this is pretty easy to check. Transient means an instance per resolution, singleton will have it's own instance of transient service with matching it's lifetime/scope (it does not matter if you resolve singleton from scope or not, it is still in the root provider).

Thank you, but wouldn't the singleton stop working, if it's depending on a scoped service, which would get disposed, when exiting the scoped service's scope (using declaration)?
